# Scatterplot age against no y variable

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to recreate a graph like below using R to visualize the age distribution of a sample with no success.
It is a scatterplot of age, which I assume has been jittered or something similar to spread out the values up the y axis, and there is no y variable.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[age distribution scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1LHA.png)

Comment: You could plot the age values against randomly generated y values acting as the jitter

Comment: A scatterplot it is always a two-way plot. Otherwise you are trying to do an Histogramm

Comment: `stripchart(rpois(100, 25), method = 'jitter')` or `stripchart(rpois(100, 25), method = 'stack')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do an scatterplot,

```
set.seed(5)

ages <- rnorm(100,mean=50, sd=7)
random_values <- rnorm(100, 0, 7) 

plot(ages, random_values)
```

If you have age as a single variable you always can do an Histogramm

```
hist(ages)
```

If you have number of t by age, you may be want to do a pyramid population plot